# Do we need a new APNS certificate for each app update?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

This may sound like a dumb question, but is one APNS certificate good for an app and all it's subsequent updates?? If I have v1.0 of my app that supports pushes, and decide to release v1.1, can 1.1 use the same APNS certificate as 1.0??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One certificate is enough, it's linked to the bundle identifier, not the version. I have many versions of many apps using APNS running.

One thing you should notice is that if you run on testflight you need to use the production certificate.

And if you do APNS and have trouble, try EasyAPNS, it has worked well for me.